# How to print all the items in a Bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, printing, carousel

I'm new to Bootstrap (2.x still) and was looking for a way to display all items in a carousel when printing.

I didn't find anything pointers, so here's what I did to get started:

- bootstrap.css hides the carousel items thusly:

  .carousel-inner > .item { 
   display: none ....
- When I want to print, dynamically modify the .css of the of items to display.  This stacks them all up.

  $('.item').css("display", "block");
- For my application, I wanted a multipage document, one page per carousel item.   I also added a forced page break to my @media print { } section:

  .item {
  page-break-after:always;}

Hopefully this will save someone some time.   If there's a better way, please add!

Thanks!  I can't count the number of times stackoverflow saved me a ton of time.
  James

Answer (score 4):

I use this css

```
@media print {
 .carousel-indicators{display: none;}
 .item{display:block;}
 .item { page-break-after:always;}
};
```

**Don't forget** to specify image height !

```
<img src="img.png" height="400" alt="...">
```

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap version 4, it is ".carousel-item" not ".item":

```
@media print {

   .carousel-item { 
     display: block; /* display all slides for print media */
   }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to add !important to make it work. And if you are using fades, you’ll need to add opacity too:

```
@media print {
   .carousel-item { 
     display: block !important;
     opacity: 1 !important;
   }

};
```